# What is causing this glitch in my cdkdragdrop module?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material, angular-cdk, angular-cdk-drag-drop

this is my first question on Stack Overflow so pardon my etiquette.

I have a droplist which contains boxes (divs) which are also droplists. These boxes allow images to be dropped on them. I want to be able to move these boxes to anywhere on the main droplist so I get the x and y coordinates onDragMoved and then set the box's location to those coordinates onDragEnded. This works but there is a small glitch that happens before the box snaps to that location. Please look at the video I have attached. [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HIWRm.jpg). It's very hard to notice but the box fills the whole droplist for a few seconds before it snaps to the location it was dropped on.

Here is my code for the droplist:

```
 <mat-card fxFlex="63%" style="padding:0px;background-color:transparent;"
              fxLayout="column" fxLayoutAlign="stretch">
      <div fxLayout="row nowrap" fxLayoutAlign="start center"
           style="background: transparent linear-gradient(0deg, #222D64 0%, #22274E 200%) 0% 0% no-repeat padding-box;height: 60px; width: 100%; padding: 0px 5px 0px 5px;">
        <button fxFlex="35px" mat-button fxLayout="column" fxLayoutAlign="center center"
                [innerHTML]="cachedIcons[importedIconsEnum.singleView]"
                [style.stroke]="(routingMode==='1' ? '#22BCFC' : 'white')"
                style="height:35px;width:35px;padding:0px;"
                [disabled]="false"
                matTooltip="One to one routing mode"
                matTooltipPosition="below"
                (click)="routingModeChanged('1')">
        </button>
        <div fxFlex="45px"></div>
        <button fxFlex="35px" mat-button fxLayout="column" fxLayoutAlign="space-around center"
                [innerHTML]="cachedIcons[importedIconsEnum.multiview]"
                [style.stroke]="(routingMode==='2' ? '#22BCFC' : 'white')"
                style="height:35px;padding:0px;"
                [disabled]="false"
                matTooltip="Multiview routing mode"
                matTooltipPosition="below"
                (click)="routingModeChanged('2')">
        </button>
        <div fxFlex="45px" style="height:40px;border-right:1px solid #606FB4;"></div>
        <div fxFlex="45px"></div>
        <button fxFlex="35px" mat-button fxLayout="column" fxLayoutAlign="space-around center"
                style="height:35px;padding:0px;"
                matTooltip="Notifications"
                matTooltipPosition="below"
                (click)="requestNotifications()">
          <mat-icon style="transform: scale(1.5)" [ngStyle]="{'color': (hasNotification ? 'yellow' : 'white')}">notifications</mat-icon>
        </button>
        <div fxFlex="45px" *ngIf="selectedLayout  && routingMode === '2' "></div>
        <button fxFlex="35px" mat-button fxLayout="column" fxLayoutAlign="center center"
                *ngIf="selectedLayout  && routingMode === '2'"
                [innerHTML]="(isMultiviewLocked === true ? cachedIcons[importedIconsEnum.lock] : cachedIcons[importedIconsEnum.unlock])"
                style="height:35px;padding:0px;"
                [style.stroke]="(isMultiviewLocked===false ? '#22BCFC' : 'white')"
                [style.fill]="(isMultiviewLocked===false ? '#22BCFC' : 'white')"
                [disabled]="!selectedLayout || selectedLayout.isOneToOne"
                matTooltip="Lock/unlock multiview"
                matTooltipPosition="below"
                (click)="lockMultiview()">
        </button>
        <div fxFlex="45px" *ngIf="selectedLayout  && routingMode === '2'"></div>
        <button fxFlex="35px" mat-button fxLayout="column" fxLayoutAlign="center center"
                [innerHTML]="cachedIcons[importedIconsEnum.swap]"
                *ngIf="selectedLayout && routingMode === '2'"
                style="height:35px;padding:0px;"
                [style.stroke]="(!selectedLayout || selectedLayout.isOneToOne ? 'gray' : (isSwapEnabled === true ? '#22BCFC' : 'white'))"
                [style.fill]="(!selectedLayout || selectedLayout.isOneToOne ? 'gray' : (isSwapEnabled === true ? '#22BCFC' : 'white'))"
                [disabled]="!selectedLayout || selectedLayout.isOneToOne"
                matTooltip="Swap video sources"
                matTooltipPosition="below"
                (click)="swapModeChanged()">
        </button>
        <div fxFlex="45px"></div>
        <button fxFlex="35px" mat-button fxLayout="column" fxLayoutAlign="center center"
                [innerHTML]="cachedIcons[importedIconsEnum.music]"
                style="height:35px;stroke:white;padding:0px;"
                matTooltip="Play music"
                matTooltipPosition="below"
                (click)="showMusicPage()">
        </button>
        <div fxFlex="45px"></div>
        <button fxFlex="35px" mat-button fxLayout="column" fxLayoutAlign="center center"
                [innerHTML]="cachedIcons[importedIconsEnum.record]"
                style="height:35px;stroke:white;padding:0px;"
                matTooltip="Start / stop video recording"
                matTooltipPosition="below"
                [disabled]="dataCache.previewDeviceID === undefined || !selectedLayout"
                (click)="setVideoRecording()"
                [class.blinking]="isRecording">
        </button>
        <div fxFlex="45px"></div>
        <button fxFlex="35px" mat-button fxLayout="column" fxLayoutAlign="center center"
                [innerHTML]="cachedIcons[importedIconsEnum.download]"
                style="height:35px;stroke:white;padding:0px;"
                matTooltip="Download recorded videos"
                matTooltipPosition="below"
                (click)="downloadVideoRecording()"
                [class.blinking]="isDownloading">
        </button>
        <div fxFlex="45px" *ngIf="dataCache.clientType===1"></div>
        <button fxFlex="35px" mat-button fxLayout="column" fxLayoutAlign="center center"
                [innerHTML]="(dataCache.isPrivate===true ? cachedIcons[importedIconsEnum.privacyOn] : cachedIcons[importedIconsEnum.privacy])"
                style="height:35px;stroke:white;padding:0px;"
                matTooltip="Turn ON/OFF privacy"
                matTooltipPosition="below"
                [disabled]="!dataCache.previewDeviceID || !selectedLayout"
                *ngIf="dataCache.clientType===1"
                (click)="setPrivacy()">
        </button>
        <div fxFlex="45px" *ngIf="dataCache.clientType===1"></div>
        <button fxFlex="32px" mat-button fxLayout="column" fxLayoutAlign="center center"
                [innerHTML]="cachedIcons[importedIconsEnum.usb]"
                style="height:35px;stroke:white;padding:0px;"
                [style.stroke]="'white'"
                [style.fill]="'white'"
                matTooltip="Pair HID USB"
                matTooltipPosition="below"
                [disabled]="!selectedLayout || dataCache.previewHasUsbHid() === false"
                *ngIf="dataCache.clientType===1"
                (click)="setUsbDecoder(dataCache.previewDeviceID, $event)"
                matBadge="{{dataCache.getPreviewUsbIndex()}}" [matBadgeHidden]="dataCache.getPreviewUsbIndex()===0"
                matBadgePosition="before" matBadgeColor="warn">
        </button>
        <div fxFlex="45px"></div>
        <button fxFlex="35px" mat-button fxLayout="column" fxLayoutAlign="center center"
                [innerHTML]="cachedIcons[importedIconsEnum.close]"
                style="height:35px;stroke:white;padding:0px;"
                (click)="clearDisplayLayout($event, previewId)"
                [disabled]="dataCache.previewDeviceID === undefined"
                matTooltip="Clear layout from preview"
                matTooltipPosition="below">
        </button>
        <div fxFlex></div>
        <button mat-button
                fxLayout="column" fxLayoutAlign="center center"
                [matMenuTriggerFor]="layoutMenu"
                #otherMenuTrigger="matMenuTrigger"
                (menuOpened)="menuOpened()"
                (menuClosed)="menuClosed()">
          <span class="device-list-title">Other Activities</span>
          <i class="material-icons" *ngIf="isMenuOpen===false" style="font-size:32px;">expand_more</i>
          <i class="material-icons" *ngIf="isMenuOpen===true" style="font-size:32px;">expand_less</i>
        </button>
        <mat-menu #layoutMenu="matMenu">
          <ng-template matMenuContent let-name="name">
            <button mat-menu-item (click)="requestNetStat()" color="primary">
              <div fxLayout="row" fxLayoutAlign="start center">
                <i class="material-icons" style="font-size:24px;">network_check</i>&nbsp;&nbsp;
                <span class="menu-item-text">Bandwidth Usage</span>
              </div>
            </button>
            <button mat-menu-item color="primary" fxLayout="row nowrap" fxLayoutAlign="start center"
                    [matMenuTriggerFor]="saveMenu"
                    [disabled]="!dataCache.previewDeviceID || selectedLayout === null || !selectedLayout || selectedLayout.isSaved === true || selectedLayout.isOneToOne"
                    *ngIf="dataCache.clientType===1 || dataCache.clientType===3">
              <i class="material-icons" style="font-size:24px;">save</i>&nbsp;&nbsp;
              <span class="menu-item-text">Save</span>
            </button>
            <mat-menu #saveMenu="matMenu">
              <div mat-menu-item *ngIf="selectedLayout" (click)="$event.stopPropagation()">
                <form fxLayout="row nowrap" fxLayoutAlign="start center">
                  <mat-form-field>
                    <input type="text" matInput placeholder="Layout Name" class="menu-item-text"
                           [(ngModel)]="selectedLayout.name" maxlength="100" [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}" />
                  </mat-form-field>
                  <button mat-raised-button color="primary" (click)="saveSelectedLayout();" style="margin-left:5px;">
                    <i class="material-icons" style="font-size:24px;">save</i>
                  </button>
                </form>
              </div>
            </mat-menu>
          </ng-template>
        </mat-menu>
      </div>
      <div style="width:100%;padding:0px;margin:0px;background-color:transparent;">
        <mat-card style="width:100%;border:0px;padding:0px;background-color:transparent;box-sizing:border-box;">
          <mat-card-content style="position:relative;width:100%;background-color:transparent;">
              <div [style.paddingTop.%]="designAreaHeightPercentage"
                   [style.backgroundColor]="'transparent'"
                   class="designArea" style="width:100%;position: relative;overflow:hidden;"
                   id="designArea" #designArea
                   cdkDropList
                 #layoutDesignList="cdkDropList"
                   [cdkDropListData]="[selectedLayout]"
                   (cdkDropListDropped)="layoutDropped($event)"
                   (cdkDropListEntered)="layoutEntered($event)"
                   (cdkDropListExited)="layoutExited($event)"
                   [cdkDropListAutoScrollDisabled]="true"
                   [cdkDropListSortingDisabled]="true">
                <img fxFill id="player" alt="Video Player"
                     *ngIf="dataCache.clientType===2 || dataCache.clientType===3"
                     style="position:absolute;left:0;top:0;right:0;bottom:0;background-color:black;width:100%;" />
                <div style="position:absolute;left:0;top:0;right:0;bottom:0;background-color:black;width:100%;font-size:xx-large;text-align:center;color:red;"
                     *ngIf="!dataCache.previewDeviceID && resultOfGetDisplaysReceived">
                  Preview device either does not exist, turned OFF, disconnected from network, or not configured for the room {{(room && room.name ? room.name : '')}}
                </div>
                <div style="position:absolute;left:0;top:0;right:0;bottom:0;background-color:black;width:100%;font-size:xx-large;text-align:center;color:red;"
                     *ngIf="hasValidLicense === false">
                 You do not have a valid license. Please contact Admin with this key: nddksdnksdn
                </div>
                <div *ngIf="dataCache.previewDeviceID != null && selectedLayout"
                     style="position:absolute;left:0;top:0;bottom:0;right:0;overflow:hidden;background-color:transparent;box-sizing:border-box;border:1px solid rgba(110, 124, 199, 0.5);">
                <ng-container *ngFor="let layoutWindow of selectedLayout.windows">
                      <div id="drag-{{layoutWindow.index}}" [style.width.%]="helper.getWidthPercent(layoutWindow.width,selectedLayout.width)"
                           [style.height.%]="helper.getHeightPercent(layoutWindow.height, selectedLayout.height)"
                           [style.top.%]="helper.getOffsetPercent(layoutWindow.verticalPosition, selectedLayout.height)"
                           [style.left.%]="helper.getOffsetPercent(layoutWindow.horizontalPosition, selectedLayout.width)"
                           style="position: absolute; border: 1px solid rgba(110, 124, 199, 0.5); overflow: hidden; background-color: transparent; box-sizing: border-box; "
                           cdkDrag (cdkDragMoved)="onDragMoved($event)" (cdkDragReleased)="onDragStopped($event)"
                           cdkDragBoundary=".designArea" [cdkDragDisabled]="selectedLayout.isOneToOne || resizing===true || isMultiviewLocked===true"
                           *ngIf="layoutWindow.index < 32 || selectedLayout.isOneToOne !== true && layoutWindow.index != 99">
                    <div #currWindow id="window-{{layoutWindow.index}}" fxFill
                             style="border:0px solid rgba(128,128,128,0.5);overflow:hidden;background-color:transparent;box-sizing:border-box;"
                             mwlResizable [enableGhostResize]="false" [resizeEnabled]="layoutWindow.index < 99"
                             [resizeSnapGrid]="{ left: 1, right: 1 }"
                             (resizeEnd)="onResizeEnd($event, layoutWindow.index)"
                             (resizeStart)="onResizeStart($event)"
                             cdkDropList
                             [cdkDropListData]="[layoutWindow]"
                             [cdkDropListDisabled]="droppingInDesignAreaDisabled===true || resizing===true"
                             [cdkDropListAutoScrollDisabled]="true"
                             [cdkDropListSortingDisabled]="true"
                             (cdkDropListDropped)="sourceDropped($event)"
                             (cdkDropListEntered)="sourceEntered($event)"
                             (cdkDropListExited)="sourceExited($event)"
                             (pinchstart)="onPinchStart($event)"
                             (pinchend)="onPinchEnd($event, layoutWindow.sourceDeviceID)"
                             (panstart)="onPanStart($event)"
                             (panend)="onPanEnd($event, layoutWindow.sourceDeviceID)">
                          <div *ngIf="layoutWindow.index<99"
                               (click)="swapSource(layoutWindow.index)">
                            <div style="position:absolute;left:0;top:0;right:0;bottom:0;overflow:hidden;background-color:transparent;box-sizing:border-box;border-width:0px;width:100%;"
                                 cdkDrag [cdkDragDisabled]="selectedLayout.isOneToOne || resizing===true">
                              <div style="position:absolute;bottom:0;background-color:rgba(11,0,0,0.5);width:100%;box-sizing:border-box;border-width:0px;height:33px;"
                                   *ngIf="layoutWindow.index < 99"
                                   fxLayout="row nowrap"
                                   fxLayoutAlign="start center">
                                <span class="device-name-window-label">{{(layoutWindow.index < 99 ? dataCache.getSourceName(layoutWindow.sourceDeviceID) : '')}}</span>

                                <div fxFlex>
                                  <div class="resize-handle-top" mwlResizeHandle [resizeEdges]="{ top: true }"
                                       *ngIf="(layoutWindow.index < 99 && (dataCache.clientType===1 || dataCache.clientType===3)) && selectedLayout.isOneToOne !== true && (selectedLayout.isPip===false || layoutWindow.index > 0) && isMultiviewLocked===false">
                                  </div>
                                </div>
                                <button fxFlex="60px" mat-icon-button (click)="zoom('Tele')" color="primary"
                                        style="padding: 0px 8px 0px 24px;"
                                        *ngIf="selectedLayout.isOneToOne">
                                  <i class="material-icons" style="font-size:32px;">zoom_in</i>
                                </button>
                                <button fxFlex="60px" mat-icon-button (click)="zoom('Wide')" color="primary"
                                        style="padding: 0px 8px 0px 24px;"
                                        *ngIf="selectedLayout.isOneToOne">
                                  <i class="material-icons" style="font-size:32px;">zoom_out</i>
                                </button>
                                <button fxFlex="60px" mat-icon-button (click)="move('Left')" color="primary"
                                        *ngIf=" selectedLayout.isOneToOne"
                                        style="padding: 0px 8px 0px 24px;">
                                  <i class="material-icons" style="font-size:32px;">arrow_back</i>
                                </button>
                                <button fxFlex="60px" mat-icon-button (click)="move('Up')" color="primary"
                                        style="padding: 0px 8px 0px 24px;"
                                        *ngIf="selectedLayout.isOneToOne">
                                  <i class="material-icons" style="font-size:32px;">arrow_upward</i>
                                </button>
                                <button fxFlex="60px" mat-icon-button (click)="move('Down')" color="primary"
                                        style="padding: 0px 8px 0px 24px;"
                                        *ngIf="selectedLayout.isOneToOne">
                                  <i class="material-icons" style="font-size:32px;">arrow_downward</i>
                                </button>
                                <button fxFlex="60px" mat-icon-button (click)="move('Right')" color="primary"
                                        style="padding: 0px 8px 0px 24px;"
                                        *ngIf="selectedLayout.isOneToOne">
                                  <i class="material-icons" style="font-size:32px;">arrow_forward</i>
                                </button>
                                <button fxFlex="60px" mat-icon-button
                                        [innerHTML]="cachedIcons[importedIconsEnum.swap]"
                                        style="stroke: rgba(176,190,197,1); fill: rgba(176,190,197,1); padding: 0px 8px 0px 24px;"
                                        [class.blinking]="layoutWindow.readyToSwap"
                                        color="primary"
                                        *ngIf="selectedLayout.isOneToOne !== true &&  dataCache.getSourceName(layoutWindow.sourceDeviceID)">
                                </button>
                                <button fxFlex="56px" mat-icon-button
                                        color="primary"
                                        style="padding: 0px 8px 0px 24px;"
                                        *ngIf="checkAudio(layoutWindow.sourceDeviceID)"
                                        (click)="routeAudio(layoutWindow.sourceDeviceID, selectedLayout.displayDeviceID, $event)">
                                  <i class="material-icons" *ngIf="isMute(layoutWindow.sourceDeviceID) === false" style="font-size:32px;">volume_up</i>
                                  <i class="material-icons" *ngIf="isMute(layoutWindow.sourceDeviceID)" style="font-size:32px;">volume_off</i>
                                </button>
                                <button fxFlex="24px" mat-icon-button fxLayout="column" fxLayoutAlign="center center"
                                        [class.blinking]="layoutWindow.sourceDeviceID===selectedDevice1ForPairing"
                                        [innerHTML]="cachedIcons[importedIconsEnum.usb]"
                                        style="stroke:rgba(176,190,197,1);fill:rgba(176,190,197,1);padding:0px 8px 0px 0px;margin-left:24px;"
                                        *ngIf="layoutWindow.isSourceActive===true && layoutWindow.sourceDeviceID && layoutWindow.isUsbHidEnabled && selectedLayout.displayDeviceID && aDecoderHasUsb === true  && dataCache.clientType===1"
                                        (click)="setUsbEncoder(layoutWindow.sourceDeviceID, $event)"
                                        matBadge="{{dataCache.getSourceUsbIndex(layoutWindow.sourceDeviceID)}}" matBadgePosition="before" matBadgeColor="warn"
                                        [matBadgeHidden]="dataCache.getSourceUsbIndex(layoutWindow.sourceDeviceID)===0">
                                </button>
                              </div>
                              <div class="resize-handle-left" mwlResizeHandle [resizeEdges]="{ left: true }"
                                   *ngIf="(layoutWindow.index < 99 && (dataCache.clientType===1 || dataCache.clientType===3)) && selectedLayout.isOneToOne !== true && (selectedLayout.isPip===false || layoutWindow.index > 0) && isMultiviewLocked===false">
                              </div>
                              <div class="resize-handle-right" mwlResizeHandle [resizeEdges]="{ right: true }"
                                   *ngIf="(layoutWindow.index < 99 && (dataCache.clientType===1 || dataCache.clientType===3)) && selectedLayout.isOneToOne !== true && (selectedLayout.isPip===false || layoutWindow.index > 0) && isMultiviewLocked===false">
                              </div>
                              <div class="resize-handle-bottom" mwlResizeHandle [resizeEdges]="{ bottom: true }"
                                   *ngIf="(layoutWindow.index < 99 && (dataCache.clientType===1 || dataCache.clientType===3)) && selectedLayout.isOneToOne !== true && (selectedLayout.isPip===false || layoutWindow.index > 0) && isMultiviewLocked===false">
                              </div>
                            </div>
                          </div>
                        </div>
                  </div>
                </ng-container>
                </div>
              </div>
          </mat-card-content>
        </mat-card>
      </div>
      <div fxFlex style="background: transparent linear-gradient(45deg, #22274E 20%, #222D64 80%) 0% 0% no-repeat padding-box;width: 100%;">
        <div *ngIf="selectedLayout && selectedLayout.windows.length > 0">
          <ptzcamera-buttons *ngIf="showPTZ(selectedLayout.windows[0].sourceDeviceID)" [deviceID]="getSourceIDOfTheDisplay(selectedLayout.displayDeviceID)"></ptzcamera-buttons>
        </div>
      </div>
    </mat-card>
```

I have tried modifying styles for the droplist and shaving off some of the events but it didn't work.

I'm from a .NET background so it would be very easy for me to miss a minute detail. Please let me know if this is the case.